# MongoDB counting with index is slower than counting without index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql, counting

I have created a Mongo collection with 1,505,000 documents.

When there is no index on `a` key, and I am doing this:

```
db.test.count({a: {$ne: "some_string"}})
```

it takes approx to 1200ms to return the amount.

When I am doing the same thing, but for this time **WITH** index on `a` key, it takes approx to 12000ms.

**Technical details**

1. Index was created using: `db.test.createIndex({a: 1})`
2. For equivalence, when using `find` instead of `count` it provides with results after 0.002 ms.
3. I am using MongoDB on my localhost.

This is the executionStats:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "db.test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$nor" : [ 
                {
                    "a" : {
                        "$eq" : "some_string"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "a" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "a" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, \"some_string\")", 
                            "(\"some_string\", MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 10318,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1505000,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1505000,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 9916,
            "works" : 1505001,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 1505000,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 12102,
            "restoreState" : 12102,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 1505000,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "nReturned" : 1505000,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 9736,
                "works" : 1505001,
                "advanced" : 1505000,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 12102,
                "restoreState" : 12102,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "docsExamined" : 1505000,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "nReturned" : 1505000,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 2479,
                    "works" : 1505001,
                    "advanced" : 1505000,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 12102,
                    "restoreState" : 12102,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "invalidates" : 0,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "a" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "a_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "a" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "a" : [ 
                            "[MinKey, \"some_string\")", 
                            "(\"some_string\", MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 1505000,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0,
                    "seenInvalidated" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "razs-MacBook",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.4.6",
        "gitVersion" : ""
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

What's the deal?

Comment: use $explain to check weather your query is using index or not. Also you will be able to debug with the help of explain

Comment: @ShumiGupta I have edited my question adding the explain.